# Ellipse Word Problem

Tags: conic-sections

The ellipse is 5 meters across and 8 meters long with decorative fountains located at the foci. How far from the center should the fountains be located? (Rounded to the nearest hundredth). How far apart are the fountains?

I feel like this problem is a lot easier than what I'm making it.

Comment: The focal distance is given by $ \ c^2 = \ $ (longer semi-axis$)^2 \ - \ $ (shorter semi-axis$)^2 \ . $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

$$2a = 8 =>  a = 4$$

$$2b = 5 =>  b = 5/2$$

$$c = \sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}$$

Part I :The distance from the center to the focus:$$c = \sqrt{39}/2$$

Part II: The fountains are 2*c apart from each other$$2c = \sqrt{39}$$